# A Study Into The Differences of Real-Time Surround Recording And Post-Production Mixing Process In Surround Sound Formats

Tags: research, surround-sound, film-mixing

I am currently conducting my dissertation which involves development of a realistic surround sound mixing technique over conventional surround sound techniques. However my key research question is "Would realistic surround sound with real life surround elements break suspension of disbelief?".

This require me into research into conventional Surround sound mixing techniques for films. however I am finding it difficult to source the right resources on current and conventional spatial mixing techniques. Would anyone have an idea as to which books I should refer to?

This research is focussing on the creative aspect of surround sound rather than the technical aspect of it. Taking into consideration the suspension of disbelief is a primary factor in creating spatial soundscapes. I am trying to develop a technique which includes the placement of foleys, incidentals and more organic elements of a sound design in surround array of speakers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Abhishek J. Pant

Comment: Quite an educative post already! I always assumed that surround stuff was always done post production, but after a brief search it turns out that (at least one) [5.1 channel mic](http://www.advancedaudiorentals.com/docs/H4_specsheet.pdf) exists.

Comment: As I have already begun research, I have stumbled onto a revelation which could possibly change and revolutionise hum perception of film. Given that the audience perceives film as a third party and hence has adjusted to the pre conceived notion of aural elements. However If I were to enforce a realistic spatial placements of sound on my surround soundscape that would substantially change the human perception of film. The audience then would perceive the film as a separate first person entity in the film. That means that they would be fully immersed in the film.